# Reload data from a drop down box created by script without having to delete the element and create another one

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

The values in my `CSV` file are constantly changing, so to update the options the least worst model I could do was to `remove the element by ID` and create a new one calling the function that creates the box again, but the page keeps moving up and down between remove element and creating a new one.

I would like help to create a way to not need remove the element during the process.

**Note: I use `D3.js` to parse `CSV` data.**

My `CSV` model data:

```
label,value
,
Bayern x Dortmund,www.google.com
Barcelona x Real Madrid,www.yahoo.com
City x Arsenal,www.duckduckgo.com
```

My current task to auto reload:

```
<script id="auto-update-csv">
    let interval_csv
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        interval_csv = setInterval(refreshcsv, 5000); // refresh every 5 secs
    })
    
    function refreshcsv() {
        document.getElementById('select-box-1').remove()
        d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(error, data){caixasuspensa1(error, data)});
    }
</script>
```

My script to create a box:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
    function caixasuspensa1(error, data) {
      var select = d3.select("#caixa-suspensa-1").append("select").attr("id","select-box-1").style("width","100%")
    
      select
        .on("change", function(d) {
          var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
          document.querySelector('#barra-de-texto-para-radar-1').value = value;
          document.getElementById('botao-do-radar-1').click();
        });
    
      select.selectAll("option")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
          .append("option")
          .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
          .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
    }
    
    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(error, data){caixasuspensa1(error, data)});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have data dependent items: the options and one structural and permanent (data-independent item): the select.

We can add our structural items once. Then in an update function, use the enter/update/exit cycle, or more simply, the join method, to ensure that we update, create, and remove options as needed from the select.

Here's an example below using selection.join. The select is appended once and outside of the update function and the update function only modifies/creates/removes elements dependent on the data: the options.

```js
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr("id","select-box")
  .style("width","347px");
  
var data = [1,2,3,4]
  
function update(data) {
  
  select.selectAll("option")
    .data(data)
    .join("option")
    .text(d=>d)
    .attr("value",d=>d);
    
}

// load initial data:
update(data);


// generate new data and pass to update();
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("update options")
  .on("click", function() {
    var min = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var length = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 + 3)
    data = d3.range(length).map(d=>d+min);
    console.log(data);
    update(data);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

While I'm not using d3.csv here, the method remains the same: when new data is available, call `update(data)` where data is the new data array. For example:

```
function refreshcsv() {
    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv").then(update);
}
```

*I'm  using d3v7, the join method was introduced late in d3v5. It appears you are using v4, in which case we need to use the enter, exit, and update selections:*

```js
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .attr("id","select-box")
  .style("width","347px");
  
var data = [1,2,3,4]
  
function update(data) {
  
  let update = select.selectAll("option")
    .data(data);
    
  update.exit().remove();
    
  update.enter().append("option").merge(update)
    .text(d=>d)
    .attr("value",d=>d);

}

// load initial data:
update(data);


// generate new data and pass to update();
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("update options")
  .on("click", function() {
    var min = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var length = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 + 3)
    data = d3.range(length).map(d=>d+min);
    console.log(data);
    update(data);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*And reverting the refreshcsv function back to v4:*

```
function refreshcsv() {
    d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(error, data) { 
           /* check for error or processing */ 
           update(data); 
   })
}
```

*Of course we need to make sure that the select element is created and selected prior to the update function running*

Comment: You still have to create the select element first - though a fiddle isn't ideal for a demo because you need to load external files. If I have time I'll produce an example.

Comment: Anyway, I managed to make it work! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot today!